# Processing.js particle system

Tags: javascript, animation, physics, processing.js

After about half an hour of fooling around with Processing.js/JavaScript, I got this fairly decent particle system set up:

```
// main particle constructor class
var Particle = function(position) {
    this.velocity = new PVector(random(-0.1, 0.1), random(-0.1, 0.1));
    this.acceleration = new PVector(random(-0.01, 0.01), random(-0.01, 0.01));
    this.lifeTime = 300;
    this.position = position.get();
};

// update the particle
Particle.prototype.update = function() {
    this.velocity.add(this.acceleration);
    this.position.add(this.velocity);
    this.lifeTime--;
};

// render the particle
Particle.prototype.render = function() {
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(161, 153, 153, this.lifeTime);
    fill(140, 135, 140, this.lifeTime);
    ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, 15, 15);
};

// check the bounds of a particle
Particle.prototype.checkBounds = function() {
    if(this.position.x >= 385) {
        this.acceleration = new PVector(random(-0.02, -0.01), random(-0.01, 0.01));
    }
    if(this.position.x <= 15) {
        this.acceleration = new PVector(random(0.01, 0.02), random(-0.01, 0.01));
    }
    if(this.position.y >= 385) {
        this.acceleration = new PVector(random(-0.01, 0.01), random(-0.02, -0.01));
    }
    if(this.position.y <= 15) {
        this.acceleration = new PVector(random(-0.01, 0.01), random(0.01, 0.02));
    }
};

// check if the particle is dead
Particle.prototype.particleDead = function() {
    if(this.lifeTime > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};

// array containing particles
var particles = [];

// main draw loop
var draw = function() {

    // draw the background and push a new particle
    background(11, 100, 209);
    particles.push(new Particle(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY)));

    // iterate through particles and run their methods
    for(var p = particles.length-1; p >= 0; p--) {
        var particle = particles[p];
        particle.checkBounds();
        particle.update();
        particle.render();
        if(particle.particleDead()) {
            particles.splice(p, 1);
        }
    }
};
```

Now, I think that this could definitely be improved, as the `Particle.prototype.checkBounds` method seems to not work all the time. Anyways, what can I improve here?

Comment: Updated my answer with an approach to fix for your `checkBounds`.

Comment: `checkBounds` does not implement hard boundaries: it just applies a force to the right if the particle is close to the left edge.

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a link to a working demo on jsfiddle or plnkr.  I don't know if it is possible with processing.js.

Comment: @toto2 https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/basic-particle-system/6132374271426560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question,

there are few things that could be improved:

- Read up on the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), it would be excellent to

  - Reduce your usage of `this`
  - Make your class look like 1 piece of code

  Something like this:

  ```
  // main particle constructor class
  function Particle(position) {

    var velocity = new PVector(random(-0.1, 0.1), random(-0.1, 0.1)),
        acceleration = new PVector(random(-0.01, 0.01), random(-0.01, 0.01)),
        lifeTime = 300,
        position = position.get();

    function update() {
      velocity.add(acceleration);
      position.add(velocity);
      lifeTime--;
    }

    function render() {
      strokeWeight(2);
      stroke(161, 153, 153, lifeTime);
      fill(140, 135, 140, lifeTime);
      ellipse(position.x,position.y, 15, 15);
    };

    return {
      update : update,
      render: render;
    }     
  };
  ```

  I obviously did not rewrite the whole thing, but you should catch my drift.
- You keep using `random(-0.1, 0.1)`, I would create a helper function for this
- `fill(140, 135, 140, lifeTime);` <- I would put a comment as to what color this should be
- Do not use an if statement to determine true or false like you do :

  ```
  // check if the particle is dead
  Particle.prototype.particleDead = function() {
      if(this.lifeTime > 0) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }
  };
  ```

  do this instead:

  ```
  // check if the particle is dead
  Particle.prototype.particleDead = function() {
      return this.lifeTime > 0
  };
  ```

  If you have time, read up on falsy values, you could also simply do `return !this.lifetime`
- I am still playing with the code, I managed to fix the right hand side bounce with this:

  ```
  if(this.position.x >= 385) {
    this.acceleration.x = random(-0.02, -0.01);
    this.velocity.x = random(-0.1, -0.01);
  }
  ```

  In essence you have to solve both the acceleration and the velocity.

I have to wonder, how do you access `random`? I can only access `random` as a function under the instance of Processing.

It is too bad that the snippets will now allow for localStorage access, so I can only give you a link to jsbin [with my refactored version](http://jsbin.com/tagefe/3/edit?js,output) and the source code here in case jsbin ever dies:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('partikals'),
    pjs = new Processing(canvas),
    width = 400,
    height = 400,
    padding = 15;

function Particle2(position) {

    var velocity = new PVector(pjs.random(-0.1, 0.1), pjs.random(-0.1, 0.1)),
        acceleration = new PVector(pjs.random(-0.01, 0.01), pjs.random(-0.01, 0.01)),
        lifeTime = 300;

    position = position.get();

    function update() {
        velocity.add(acceleration);
        position.add(velocity);
        lifeTime--;
    }

    function render() {
        pjs.strokeWeight(2);
        //Each particle is grey
        pjs.stroke(161, 153, 153, lifeTime);
        pjs.fill(140, 135, 140, lifeTime);
        pjs.ellipse(position.x, position.y, 15, 15);
    }

    function isDead() {
        return !lifeTime;
    }

    //I wonder if just *= -1 would work
    function bounce() {
        if (position.x > width - padding) {
            acceleration.x = -Math.abs(acceleration.x);
            velocity.x = -Math.abs(velocity.x);
        }
        if (position.x < padding) {
            acceleration.x = Math.abs(acceleration.x);
            velocity.x = Math.abs(velocity.x);
        }
        if (position.y > height - padding) {
            acceleration.y = -Math.abs(acceleration.y);
            velocity.y = -Math.abs(velocity.y);
        }
        if (position.y < padding) {
            acceleration.y = Math.abs(acceleration.y);
            velocity.y = Math.abs(velocity.y);
        }
    }

    return {
        update: update,
        render: render,
        isDead: isDead,
        bounce: bounce
    };
}

// array containing particles
var particles = [];

pjs.setup = function() {
    pjs.size(width, height);
    pjs.frameRate(24);
};

pjs.draw = function() {

    //Clear by drawing the background and push a new particle
    pjs.background(11, 100, 209);
    particles.push(new Particle2(new PVector(pjs.mouseX, pjs.mouseY)));

    // iterate through particles and run their methods
    for (var p = particles.length - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
        var particle = particles[p];
        particle.bounce();
        particle.update();
        particle.render();
        if (particle.isDead()) {
            particles.splice(p, 1);
        }
    }
};

pjs.setup();
```

Comment: I use Khanacademy to program, they must have some special features to make things easier.

Comment: +1 for some good points, but I have a few concerns: A revealing JavaScript module is an IIFE - not a constructor function, just as described in your link. In my opinion, if OP wants to use the revealing module pattern, it should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jw9cj6pj/ Your current `update` and `render` functions will be redefined for each new `Particle` that is instantiated, which is bad from a performance point of view.

Comment: @Johan There is no performance problem, but there is a memory cost. Given that in this code, you can have at most 200 instances, I think this is still the right approach.

Comment: There is a fine line between over-engineering and maintainability, but since using the `prototype` adds little to no overhead, I think despite the current(!) limit you should not waste the memory. Changing the design is much harder later on.